# Python subprocess.check_call terminate and start from where it terminated

Tags: python, subprocess, terminate

I am trying to automatize some test cases using subprocess_check.call() by calling another python script with an input and output files. I have approx. 10 input files. When I started to test, for example, first and second files were tested successfully but in the third file I got an error and the script was terminated. What I want is, how can I run my script from where it was terminated ? I do not want to start from the beginning. I just wanted to continue my test from the case where I got an error. After correcting the input file, starting from this file I want to run the script until the end.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is not a question involving code, so you get a general answer, not involving code.

**The solution to your problem requires you to *keep protocol*. This protocol must survive the lifetime of your test processes.**

So, there must be some place where you can *write to* about the state of your tests, and this place must ensure persistence. What might that be? Right, the file system, for instance. The most simple place to keep track of your tests is the file system.

What follows is one very simple example of how you might want to implement this: For each test case that succeeded, write a file to the current working directory, indicating success for this test. Then, before your test process would invoke a certain test, make it check the existence of such file and make it skip the test if the file is found. Let's assume your input files have different basenames (e.g. `A`, `B`, ...,). You can then use a file called `B.success` in the current working directory to indicate that this does not need to be tested anymore.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation ! I got the idea.

Comment: If the answer has helped, you might want to consider voting/checking it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think I have a barebones answer not using subprocess of this task (unless you really have to).

Assuming the scripts to test are of the form

script1.py

```
import sys

def main1(args):
    #do something awesome with args
    return some_cool_value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = sys.argv
    main1(filename)
```

then what you are doing is using subprocess to evaluate the output of this, when what you could be doing is something of the following:

main_test.py

```
from script1 import main1 # you may want to rename main is you have  loads of scripts

def test__main(filenames):
     for name in filenames:
          try:
              result1 = main1(name)
              # do something with result
              print "file "+ name+ " processed successfully!"
          except:
              print "file "+ name+ " not processed successfully!"



if __name__ == "__main__":

    filenames = sys.argv
    main(fienames)
```

and logging which of the files succeed as they get processed, so you can restart in the right place if necessary.

I imagine the workflow going something like this:

```
 python main_test.py passingfile1 corruptedfile2

 >>> file passingfile1 processed successfully
 >>> file corruptedfile2 not successfully processed
```

Then you could re-run you script from corruptedfile2.

Generally I try to avoid using subprocess to call python scripts, and use it only for compiled binaries, when no other interface is possible

Comment: Your answer does not provide a solution for *automatically* skipping a certain set of tests. Manual evaluation of a log file and manual adjustment of a Python script is not a valid solution. You also should have cleaned up your code semantically: `filename = sys.argv`, really? Typo: `main(fienames)`. Also, you should appreciate that running tests in different processes ensures the tests being **decoupled** to a certain degree -- this may be an important requirement in many cases, and you cannot judge about his/her requirements.

Comment: You can spawn new processes without using the subprocess module if this is important. It just seems insane to use the subprocess module to run an existing python script. I suspect I should have cleaned up the code, though really it is just a demo of an idea. It is pretty easy to edit the above approach to write the passed tests to a file as you suggest